# error "File/folder does not exists!" when attempting to load metadata.xml with run-etl-job command

Tags: fredhopper

I'm unsure why seeing error "File/folder does not exists!" when attempting to load metadata.xml with run-etl-job command, as the folder exists and the dedicated fredhopper account has read/write access to it.  Any thoughts?

**Environment details**

- Fredhopper 7.5, revision 19
- Java 1.8.0_141 x64
- Fredhopper instance name is ExperienceOptimization

**Further details**

- bin\deployment-agent running from command line
- Command syntax to load metadata.xml as below

  bin\run-etl-job STJob.kjb "-DINSTANCE=ExperienceOptimization" "-DTRIGGER=load-data" "-DUNIVERSE=catalog01" "-DEXECUTIONPATH=C:\fredhopper75\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\custom"
- etl instance kitchen.log details

> INFO  23-07 19:26:28,924 - Kitchen - Logging is at level : Basic logging
>
> INFO  23-07 19:26:28,939 - Kitchen - Start of run.
>
> INFO  23-07 19:26:29,189 - STJob - Start of job execution
>
> INFO  23-07 19:26:29,210 - STJob - Starting entry [Move Files]
>
> ERROR 23-07 19:26:29,220 - Move Files - File/folder [C:\fredhopper75\data\instances\ExperienceOptimization\custom../../../../ExperienceOptimization/data/fas-xml-incremental/catalog01/] does not exists!
>
> INFO  23-07 19:26:29,224 - STJob - Finished job entry [Move Files] (result=[false])
>
> INFO  23-07 19:26:29,225 - STJob - Job execution finished
>
> INFO  23-07 19:26:29,226 - Kitchen - Finished!
>
> ERROR 23-07 19:26:29,227 - Kitchen - Finished with errors
>
> INFO  23-07 19:26:29,227 - Kitchen - Start=2017/07/23 19:26:28.939, Stop=2017/07/23 19:26:29.227
>
> INFO  23-07 19:26:29,227 - Kitchen - Processing ended after 0 seconds.

- Folder "C:\fredhopper\ExperienceOptimization\data\fas-xml-incremental\catalog01" exists and have given the Everyone group read/write access
  [image: filesystem screenshot]
- Same error recurs after removing previous install and reinstalling Fredhopper.
- Fredhopper cluster created via topology.txt, custom directory created, trigger-types.xml and business.xml added to the config directory of ExperienceOptimization.
- jars from documentation added to the custom folder of ExperienceOptimization.
- Query server restarted and confirmed to be running via `"http://localhost:8177/instance/ExperienceOptimization/process/qserver/verb/status"
- When browsing to "http://localhost:8180/fredhopper/admin/", see status message "business manager will be available when the indices are loaded" (this is expected, as no data has been loaded yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is Java, you should either use double backslashes or use forward slashes. So this command should work for you:

```
bin\run-etl-job STJob.kjb "-DINSTANCE=ExperienceOptimization" "-DTRIGGER=load-data" "-DUNIVERSE=catalog01" "-DEXECUTIONPATH=C:/fredhopper75/data/instances/ExperienceOptimization/custom"
```

Comment: Many thanks Peter.  Moving answer flag to this answer as I am able to run the default STJob.kjb file using forward slashes in the -DEXECUTIONPATH param.  Also note a trailing forward slash is required as below
    "-DEXECUTIONPATH=C:/fredhopper75/data/instances/ExperienceOptimization/custom/"

Answer (score 1):

I'm also completely stuck at this point as well. I've just managed to resolve this and I believe there is a problem within the STJob.kjb

Find the  section within the STJob.kjb e.g.

```
  <fields>
    <field>
      <source_filefolder>${EXECUTIONPATH}..&#47;..&#47;..&#47;..&#47;${INSTANCE}&#47;data&#47;fas-xml-incremental&#47;${UNIVERSE}&#47;</source_filefolder>
      <destination_filefolder>${EXECUTIONPATH}..&#47;..&#47;${INSTANCE}&#47;data&#47;xml&#47;incoming&#47;batch&#47;</destination_filefolder>
      <wildcard>.*\.xml$</wildcard>
    </field>
  </fields>
```

Change this to the following

```
  <fields>
    <field>
      <source_filefolder>D:\fredhopper\data\instances\liveindexer\data\fas-xml-incremental\catalog01</source_filefolder>
      <destination_filefolder>D:\fredhopper\data\instances\liveindexer\data\xml\incoming\batch</destination_filefolder>
      <wildcard>.*\.xml$</wildcard>
    </field>
  </fields>
```

In my case, my instance name is liveindexer - just change yours to ExperienceOptimization and change your drive letter to C:\

My log now says the following

```
INFO  24-07 10:42:06,201 - Kitchen - Logging is at level : Basic logging
INFO  24-07 10:42:06,205 - Kitchen - Start of run.
INFO  24-07 10:42:06,250 - STJob - Start of job execution
INFO  24-07 10:42:06,258 - STJob - Starting entry [Move Files]
INFO  24-07 10:42:06,265 - STJob - Starting entry [Success]
INFO  24-07 10:42:06,266 - STJob - Finished job entry [Success] (result=[true])
INFO  24-07 10:42:06,266 - STJob - Finished job entry [Move Files] (result=[true])
INFO  24-07 10:42:06,266 - STJob - Job execution finished
INFO  24-07 10:42:06,267 - Kitchen - Finished!
INFO  24-07 10:42:06,267 - Kitchen - Start=2017/07/24 10:42:06.205, Stop=2017/07/24 10:42:06.267
INFO  24-07 10:42:06,267 - Kitchen - Processing ended after 0 seconds.
```

Comment: Noting that hardcoding the path to catalog01 also resolved issue for me, many thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear that Terry. Everything is working for me now. Seeing content in my Business Manager now.

Answer (score -1):

It's known issue there is a problem with the `smarttarget_api_extension.jar` that comes with SDL Web 8, so you can work around it by using the one from 2014 SP1.

Copy the `smarttarget_api_extension.jar` from Installation media folder of Tridion 2014 SP1 to your fredhopper `\custom` directory or Contact SDL Support to get the right `smarttarget_api_extension.jar`.

I hope that it helps you to resolve your issue.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this same issue Velmurugan. Using the .jars from Tridion 2014 SP1 also did not fix this issue (for me)

Comment: Also saw that removing jars did not resolve issue, thanks.